# How do I configure ZFS to panic on da (SCSI) disk failure?

Tags: freebsd, scsi, kernel-panic, carp

Situation: two redundant FreeBSD machines using CARP to share a primary IP, running a frontend proxy (E.G. HAproxy or nginx)

Primary machine experiences a loss of SCSI disk (E.G. disk failure, SAN storage failure, etc) and services fail (L7 timeouts on the web service, for example) because of the loss of disk access. However because the kernel is alive, CARP does not fail over to the backup.

How can I configure the machine to panic if the disk errors exceed a certain threshold so that the machine will stop sending CARP advertisements and the backup will take over?

Comment: Old post, but for future reference. This may be worth checking https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2017-March/086882.html

# sysctl -d net.inet.carp.demotion
net.inet.carp.demotion: Adjust demotion factor (skew of advskew)

That is form 2017, but even if actual name may have changed there may still be equivalent today. To force CARP to failover

Answer (score 0):

You can call upon NMI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422708/how-to-send-nmi-on-same-system

Why panic when you can just shutdown though?